# How to make the hyperlink point to the top of linked figure and item of enumeration?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumerate, links, labels

I want to create a problem booklet. Each problem numbered by `enumerate` has at most one figure that may either be in `marginpar` or float and occupy the full width.

The caption for each figure has a hyperlink to the corresponding question. From the question, we also has a link to the corresponding figure.

I use auto-generated labels

```
\def\qMark{Q.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{enumi}}
\def\fMark{F.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{enumi}}
```

to establish the linking.

I add `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}` to get a better linking behavior, i.e., clicking a hyperlink will direct us to the top of the linked object rather than to the point that requires us to adjust the view.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    vmargin=2cm,
    outermargin=9cm,
    innermargin=2cm,
    marginparwidth=7cm,
    marginparsep=20pt
]{geometry}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}


\def\qMark{Q.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{enumi}}
\def\fMark{F.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{enumi}}

\let\tempItem=\item
\renewcommand\item{\tempItem\label{\qMark}}

\def\getQRef{Problem~\ref{\qMark}}
\def\getFRef{\figurename~\ref{\fMark}}


\newcommand\MarginFig{%
\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{For \getQRef.}\label{\fMark}%
}}

\newcommand\FullFig{%
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \checkoddpage
  \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}%
    \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{% 
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{For \getQRef.}
        \label{\fMark}}}
\end{figure}
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Higgs Boson}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\MarginFig
\getFRef\
\lipsum[1]

\item
\lipsum[1]

\item
\FullFig
\lipsum[1]\getFRef.

\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]\getFRef.

\item
\FullFig
\lipsum[1]\getFRef.

\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]\getFRef.

\item
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, clicking, for example, `Figure 1.3` or `Problem 3` does not behave as they are supposed to be. Please try them by yourself to get the idea.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the `\label` at the top of the box. (I also added some `%` at ends of lines)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    vmargin=2cm,
    outermargin=9cm,
    innermargin=2cm,
    marginparwidth=7cm,
    marginparsep=20pt
]{geometry}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}


\def\qMark{Q.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{enumi}}
\def\fMark{F.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{enumi}}

\let\tempItem=\item
\renewcommand\item{\tempItem\leavevmode\label{\qMark}\ignorespaces}

\def\getQRef{Problem~\ref{\qMark}}
\def\getFRef{\figurename~\ref{\fMark}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\MarginFig{%
\marginpar{%
\refstepcounter{figure}%
\label{\fMark}%
\let\refstepcounter\@gobble
\let\H@refstepcounter\@gobble
\let\hyper@@anchor\@gobble
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
\captionof{figure}{For \getQRef.}%
}}

\newcommand\FullFig{%
\begin{figure}[hbtp]%
    \checkoddpage
  \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}%
\refstepcounter{figure}%
    \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{\label{\fMark}% 
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}{%
\let\refstepcounter\@gobble
\let\H@refstepcounter\@gobble
\let\hyper@@anchor\@gobble
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
        \caption{For \getQRef.}}}%
\end{figure}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Higgs Boson}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\MarginFig
\getFRef\
\lipsum[1]

\item
\lipsum[1]

\item
\FullFig
\lipsum[1]\getFRef.

\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]\getFRef.

\item
\FullFig
\lipsum[1]\getFRef.

\item
\MarginFig
\lipsum[1]\getFRef.

\item
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see a "Problem 3" link, just links like "Figure 1.3" in the main text which this does make link to the top Oh You mean the ones in the citation? that's your item definition. back in a bit...

Comment: try now, modified your `\item` command

Comment: How about a local redefinition of `\caption` that doesn't `\refstepcounter`, but just `\stepcounter` inside `\MarginFig`? That is, after issuing a manual `\refstepcounter`, you `\def\refstepcounter{\stepcounter}`.

Comment: It means you have a duplicated label so one of the links won't work messing with hyperref internals...

Comment: @Werner or make it a no-op then I wouldn't have to add -1. testing.....

Comment: That seems to work, code updated

Comment: using `[t]` increases the chance of it going to the end of the document as its main effect is to disallow `p` (as `t` is already allowed) so if the figure is too large to go at the top of a text page and float pages are disallowed LaTeX can put it nowhere, so it drifts to the end.

Comment: Sorry caption package directly uses hyperref's H@refstepcounter so need to disable that as well as the standard version code updated

Comment: The warning message comes again :-)

Comment: code now zaps \let\hyper@@anchor\@gobble as well. (You have too many packages redefining the same set of commands:-)

Answer (score 3):

[`hypcap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypcap) *modifies* four environments (with the option `all`): `figure`, `figure*`, `table` and `table*`. The following lines in `hypcap.sty` initiate the redefinition via `\hypcapredef`:

```
\DeclareOption{figure}{\hypcapredef{\CurrentOption}}
\DeclareOption{figure*}{\hypcapredef{\CurrentOption}}
\DeclareOption{table}{\hypcapredef{\CurrentOption}}
\DeclareOption{table*}{\hypcapredef{\CurrentOption}}
\DeclareOption{all}{%
  \hypcapredef{figure}%
  \hypcapredef{figure*}%
  \hypcapredef{table}%
  \hypcapredef{table*}%
}
```

The reason for this modification is because it has to place the hyper reference anchor at the start of the environment rather than at the call to `\caption`. So, in short, `hypcap` will not perform as expected if you "use it" outside of these four environments.

The way around it is to use one of those environments *without* making it float - that's what a `\marginpar` does anyway. For this, the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) comes in handy, since it provides the `H` float specifier. The following definition of `\MarginFig` therefore works as expected:

```
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
\newcommand\MarginFig{%
  \marginpar{%
    \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}
      \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        %\captionof{figure}{For \getQRef.}\label{\fMark}%
        \caption{For \getQRef.}\label{\fMark}%
      \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
  }}
```

The additional wrap inside a `minipage` is to ensure the proper width of the resulting figure. You may experience a difference in the vertical alignment of your `\marginpar` since its contents is wrapped inside a `minipage`. This is typical of `minipage`'s behaviour, so some adjustments might be necessary.

Comment: @HiggsBoson: That could be because [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) doesn't like it when you play around with counters when using a label. His solution could work if you modify `\caption` locally to *not* `\refstepcounter`, but rather just `\stepcounter`.

Comment: probably you want to use minipage `[t]` positioning to avoid the vertical shift from its default centering,

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=5348238#5348238