Hyperref Links Jump to Caption Instead of Image in Custom Boxed Figure Environment
I'm using a custom LaTeX command (\boxfigure) to create boxed figures with captions and optional content in the margin. However, when referencing the figure using \ref, the hyperlink in the PDF jumps to the caption of the figure instead of the top of the boxed figure or the image itself.
This issue persists despite using the hyperref and caption packages, with the hypcap option enabled. I want the hyperlink to target the top of the figure (or the image) rather than the caption.
The current hyperlink jumps to caption (red arrow) while I would like it to jump to top of either the box or figure (blue arrows).

MWE:
\documentclass{memoir}

% Required packages
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % For the custom box
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{xcolor} % For standard color definitions
\usepackage{caption} % For fixed captions
\usepackage{mwe} % Provides example images like "example-image"
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks and references

% Define the photobar tcolorbox with standard colors
\newtcolorbox{photobar}{
    colback=lightgray, % Light gray background
    coltext=blue, % Blue text
    left=1in, % Left padding
    right=0.75in, % Right padding
    sidebyside, % Enables side-by-side content
    lefthand width=2.5in, % Width of the left side
    sidebyside gap=0.2in, % Gap between left and right
    lower separated=false, % No gap in the lower section
    boxrule=0pt, % No border
    arc=0pt, % Square corners
    spread sidewards, % Spread content horizontally
    enlarge left by=-1.51in % Extend box into the left margin
}

% Define fixed caption for figures
\newfixedcaption{\boxfigurecaption}{figure}

% Define the boxfigure command
\newcommand{\boxfigure}[5][width=\textwidth]{
  \begin{photobar}
    #5 % Optional content in the margin
    \tcblower
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2} % Image
    \boxfigurecaption{#3\label{#4}} % Caption with label
  \end{photobar}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Example Boxed Figure}
This is a reference to a Figure \ref{fig:example} for demonstration.

\boxfigure{example-image}{This is a caption for the figure.}{fig:example}{
  This is optional content placed in the margin.
}

\end{document}


See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63506/161015

welcome! I would be cautious with the solution @SimonDispa linked. while it doesn't obviously break things when compiled, things have changed an enormous amount where labels, hyperref etc. are concerned. that is, it might be OK, but I'd say that would be more by luck than anything else.

You don't have a float, so caption can not insert the anchor automatically, but you can use the tools it provides: if you put the \captionsetup for example before the graphic it will create the anchor there:
\documentclass{memoir}

% Required packages
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % For the custom box
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{xcolor} % For standard color definitions
\usepackage{caption} % For fixed captions
\usepackage{mwe} % Provides example images like "example-image"
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks and references

% Define the photobar tcolorbox with standard colors
\newtcolorbox{photobar}{
    colback=lightgray, % Light gray background
    coltext=blue, % Blue text
    left=1in, % Left padding
    right=0.75in, % Right padding
    sidebyside, % Enables side-by-side content
    lefthand width=2.5in, % Width of the left side
    sidebyside gap=0.2in, % Gap between left and right
    lower separated=false, % No gap in the lower section
    boxrule=0pt, % No border
    arc=0pt, % Square corners
    spread sidewards, % Spread content horizontally
    enlarge left by=-1.51in % Extend box into the left margin
}

% Define the boxfigure command
\newcommand{\boxfigure}[5][width=\textwidth]{
  \begin{photobar}
    #5 % Optional content in the margin
    \tcblower
    \captionsetup{type=figure}%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2} % Image    
    \caption{#3\label{#4}} % Caption with label
  \end{photobar}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Example Boxed Figure}

This is a reference to a Figure \ref{fig:example} for demonstration.
\newpage 


\boxfigure{example-image}{This is a caption for the figure.}{fig:example}{
  This is optional content placed in the margin.
}

\end{document}


Thank you! This fixed everything and works great!
Reading 7.7 of caption package documentations helped a lot as well.
